# Related to social media like and share buttons

Tags: asp.net, facebook-like, social-networking

Which is the best method to add like and share buttons of Facebook and Twitter and Google+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the API documentation for how to integrate facebook functionality into an ASP.NET site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/

Start with that and then once have the facebook integration figured out it should be simple to find twitter and google+ APIs to do the same for them.

Comment: this for share link i need to share an article from the web site how can i do this?

Comment: uh, you share a link to the article? I'm pretty sure facebook takes care of the formatting and preview displays